# XML-RPC Parser?

Tags: javascript, parsing, titanium, xml-rpc, appcelerator

Hello I'm building an iPhone app in Appcelerator Titanium and one feature I'd like to add is forum support for a SMF 2.0 forum. I've installed the Tapatalk API on the forum and have successfully got my app sending an XML-RPC request and retrieving a massive XML-RPC result with all the root forum information. However I've had no luck finding a XML-RPC parser for Javascript. I'd like to able to just feed the response to a library and get back an array with each member and sub-member indexed appropriately. Does anyone know of such a library or even a better way to get SMF forum information in an XML format? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know such a library, but, XML-RPC is, well, XML, with pretty simple structure. And there are at least 3 approaches in modern javascript you can use to fetch data from xml:

- using pure DOM - `responseXML.documentElement.getElementByTagName('param')` and so on.
- [using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) XSLT proc
- using Xpath (via document.evaluate)

  Also, you can take any js xml/xsl/xpath library aimed to mitigate issues related to portability and so on.

  Nevertheless, yes, it is not so trivial task to handle XMLRPC - there are integers, dates and some other subtle issues. But a 90-95% perfectness can be reached pretty fast)

Comment: All right that's what I  figured. Not looking forward to it since I have a nested forum structure to work with though its mainly byte arrays, strings and ids. Thanks.

Comment: Found the right library. It was a bit buggy but I got it to work. It's called Mimic: http://mimic-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/